# get user city and country in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I am new to react native (and app developing) and I want to show a message to the user when he uses the app for the first time that tells the user that the app thinks he is in city CITY, in country COUNTRY.

I could not find a working example that I can use. Most of what I found are APIs that give the longitude and latitudes of the user, and some other APIs that decode (lon., lat.) into city and country. Both were not well documented with a valid working example

How may I achieve this goal? Is/are there methods or plugin(s) that I can use?

Here is a piece of code (I tried many examples) I tried:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native'

    const requestPermission = () => {
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios') return Promise.resolve(true)
    return PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'Allow to get coordinates',
        'message': 'This app requires GPS coordinates in order to proceed '
      }
    ).then(granted => {
        if(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          return Promise.resolve("You can use the location")
        } else {
          return Promise.reject("Location permission denied")
        }
    })
    }

    const getCoordinates = () => {
    return requestPermission().then(ok => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const options = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 
{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:5000}
                                        : 
{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:5000,maximumAge:2000};
            global.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options)
      })
    })
    }

    export default getCoordinates
```

The error I get is this:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Please share the impacted code you tried

Comment: I updated my question with one piece of code I used.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get current Location (require location permission granted) (remove myLocationCallback)

[image]

2. Pass location(latitude, longitude) to Google Map API (you need google **api key**)
   [image]

Comment: Declaration or statement expected. it gives an error like that, at the "static locationToAddress"